# sybase get records between two dates, being the dates expressed as VARCHARS

Tags: sql, select, sybase, sqldatetime

When I execute:

```
SELECT some_fields 
FROM some_table  
WHERE some_other_field BETWEEN '20130901' AND '20131131'
```

I get Error (247) Arithmetic overflow during implicit conversion of VARCHAR value '20131131' to SMALLDATETIME field.**

But when I execute:

```
SELECT some_field  
FROM some_table 
WHERE some_other_field BETWEEN  '20130901' AND '20131130'
```

no complains.
 (Sybase 15.7.0)

Comment: November only has 30 days, 20131131 can't be converted to a date because it doesn't exist

Comment: Damn ... that's right, tought it didn´t work for any 31 day but it did worked with '20131231' ... ashamed :S

Comment: @Kelix. you should put that as an answer.

Comment: Certainly I would take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

November only has 30 days, 20131131 can't be converted to a date because it doesn't exist.  Change the where clause in your first statement from

```
WHERE some_other_field BETWEEN '20130901' AND '20131131'
```

to this

```
WHERE some_other_field BETWEEN '20130901' AND '20131130'
```

It should execute no problem.